# How to enlarge image?

Tags: visualforce

I have an image where i need to zoom in and zoom out the image . How do i go about it . Not getting proper solutions until now . Banging head onto this . Have taken image tag where following is the code:

```
<apex:image id="theImage" value="https://s3.amazonaws.com/{!bucketToList}/{!obj.key}? AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAJGN4J4RSRNW26IEA&amp" width="100" height="100">
</apex:image>
```

Please help !

Comment: apex images render as html images on the  browser. There you can use CSS and Javascript, for which you can better ask questions on stackoverflow.com

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Visual force support HTML and JavaScript and if you want to Zoom out and Zoom in You can use Javascipt or CSS to achieve this functionality. Following link could be useful.

You can use like this.

```
<apex:page >
<style>
img:hover {
            height: 200px;
        }
</style>
 <apex:image id="theImage" value="https://s3.amazonaws.com/{!bucketToList}/{!obj.key}? AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAJGN4J4RSRNW26IEA&amp" width="220" height="55"/>
</apex:page>
```

When you will hover on image, Image will zoom in.

[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21479102/how-to-add-zoom-in-out-on-click-to-all-img-html-tags][1]

Comment: Welcome to SF.SE Prabhat. You've linked to an excellent resource in your answer. One never knows when a link might disappear so it's always a good practice to also summarize at least some of the steps that are in the link.

Comment: Can you please help me out to achieve this through Salesforce .(apex:image)